# Is there any way to write Unit tests for Windows Phone 8.1 Store app without MVVM

Tags: c#, testing, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have built my app putting the logic in the views code behind. Is there a way to create a unit test project and test something like this? I cannot find any tutorials on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests are not related to MVVM nor specific to Windows Phone, you can test anything.

MVVM is only a design pattern that one of it's advantages is that it makes unit testing easier because it separates the coding layers

Comment: Ok, thank you! And how can I write tests for my WP8.1 store app, because I can't find any good examples. Do you know any?

Comment: You can just search for .net unit tests, because it is not specific to WP. A quick google search got me this, it looks nice
http://www.rhyous.com/programming-development/csharp-unit-test-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look.

Comment: Please mark as answered if you are satisfied

Comment: @GuyLevin: That's partly wrong. You can't unit test anything, if it's not properly separated and designed with unit tests in mind. You can almost never unit test logic that you put into code behind and it's very hard to test functionality, if you don't use Inversion of Control pattern (with or without an IoC framework)

Comment: IoC helps you test your code very much, and it is used in many modern applications, and I would recommend using it almost to anyone. But, it is absolutely not necessary, you can use your own methodology in order to test your code and there are alot of levels of testing